# Best way to compute statistics for normal upper and lower temperatures of a cooler

Tags: time-series, outliers

I have lots of temperature data and when plotted it shows events like door open for a while and the repetitive cycling of the compressor every few minutes. I would like to calculate Means for compressor on/off states that are immune from skewing from the door open. In the graph below it appears that the compressor OFF is about 40.0  and the Compressor ON is about 38.5 ( looking at the mean values of the upper and lower excluding outliers)

Traditional Modes wont work since the temps vary and many readings are halfway though a cycle ( at 39.x)
IQR does not seem to help either and I suspect I need multiple methods to massage the data to get my two results of 'high mean' and 'low mean' ( my made up terms)

I am coding in Python so have many libraries to choose from.

Any ideas how get there?

[image]

Comment: I thik you are right that you may need several different measurements. Quantiles .05 a .95 may show the the cooler is mostly doing OK. But _any_ high temperature that's not just a momentary spike may cause milk or tuna salad to spoil. Make a list of your concerns and choose a summary statistic that addresses each.

Comment: If I was to code this from scratch I would look at two sets of data. 1 would be all local minimums - all points where the previous and subsequent  x(3?) points were higher. 2 would be the opposite for local maximums after excluding all points above 3rd Quartile. Once I had these then I could get the mean of each. Doable but it would be nie if someone has done this already as a library function